# RAM won't clear (diffusers)

Tags: python, torch, diffusers

I'm writing a script that needs to change models sometimes (diffusers & llama-cpp-python)
I don't have much RAM and VRAM, so I need to clean RAM and VRAM after using a model.

llama is fine, I just use

```
del(llama_object)
gc.collect()
```

That's enough and the RAM is cleared.
But diffusers doesn't want to give the same result.

```
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(...)
#at this point i have 3.4GB usage
del(pipe)
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
#at this point i have 3GB usage
```

I don't have a powerful video card, so I'm using
`pipe.enable_sequential_cpu_offload()`

I read some articles by some people who have encountered this and realized that only VRAM is cleared.

I don't know if this is necessary, but:
ram: 32GB
graphics card: GTX 960 4GB
os: manjaro linux

any suggestions?

I tried a lot of things, in one of the articles I found cleaning vram with numba

```
from numba import cuda
cuda.select_device(0)
cuda.close()
```

but I didn't get the expected result.
I also tried deleting different objects, but no result.

Comment: Hi people with the same problem! I kept digging around and found the following comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/clearing-the-gpu-is-a-headache/84762/10
I understand you can write code that runs a subprocess with the diffusers model until the model is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

So, the only thing I came up with is to create aka model.py and call it in a subprocess with parameters to run a specific model, and communicate with it via socket. when changing the model, just close the subprocess and open a new one.